# How to adjust xlim, increase the distance between each graph and set a title for the 'ridge plot' from seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to do following based on the seaborn 'ridge plot' example (https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html):

1. Adjust xlim, in order to create more distance between the error title, e.g. "Error2 - abc..." and the graph itself
2. Increase the distance between each graph
3. Set a title for the whole plot

I tried it with `sns.plt.xlim(-10, 3)`, which leads to an error.
And here is my whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})


errorNames = ['Error 1 - abc.....',
              'Error 2 - abc.....',
              'Error 3 - abc.....',
              'Error 4 - abc.....',
              'Error 5 - abc.....',
              'Error 6 - abc.....',
              'Error 7 - abc.....',
              'Error 8 - abc.....',
              'Error 9 - abc.....',
              'Error 10 - abc.....',
              'Error 11 - abc.....',
              'Error 12 - abc.....',
              'Error 13 - abc.....']


# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(650)
#g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLM"), 50)
g = np.tile(list(errorNames), 50)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
#m = df.g.map(ord)
#df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)


# sns.plt.xlim(-10, 3)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap 
# Erst hier wird geplotted
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)


# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is one way to address all the three points:

- `g.set(xlim=(-4, 3))` sets the x-limits
- `ax.text(0, .25,...)` A higher offset of 0.25 instead of 0.2 correctly positions the error names.
- `plt.suptitle('Main title')` puts a main title on the top of the figure.

---

```
g.set(xlim=(-4, 3))

def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .25, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

g.map(label, "x")
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
plt.suptitle('Main title')
```

[image]

Comment: In order to adjust the width and height of the plots one can adjust the `aspect` and `height` variable in following row `g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)`

Answer (score 0):

For 1) you can change the x limits in the same call to `g.set` when you remove the yticks:

```
g.set(yticks=[], xlim=[-5, 3])
```

For 2) you can just adjust the `hspace` value in `subplots_adjust`

For 3) you can create a `suptitle` for the figure:

```
g.fig.suptitle("Some title")
```

This gives something like:

[image]

Comment: `hspace` is only scaling the graph to the fix distance between two axes, but I would like to increase the distance  between two axes. Furthermore, I would like to scale the plot to be bigger.